# Automatically move list item to folder within the same list using SPD WorkFlow?

Tags: workflow, office-365, out-of-the-box

In my site there is a custom list with the field customer( Type of Choice). List having different folders with customer names. Now my requirement is when you add an item to that list, it will move to respective customer folder.

- My Site hosted in office 365. So i have to do this using out of box only.

How can I do this using SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, the OOB SPD workflow does not have an action to move an item to a folder. But why should it? You don't need folders (unless you have permissions in the mix). You already have the perfect metadata set up. Create a view for each customer, or create a filtered view and supply the customer with a filter web part.